# Cypress is not defined

Tags: oracle, authentication, cypress

I'm trying to connect to an oracledb and it works, but I am now trying to pass the credentials on Cypress.env() and its not working. It seems like I can't just past the env vars like this:

Helper file /helpers/db.js with the following:

```
async function getConnection() {
  return oracledb.getConnection({
    user: Cypress.env("DB_USERNAME"),
    password: Cypress.env("DB_PASSWORD"),
    connectString: Cypress.env("DB_CONNECTION_STRING")
  });
}
```

And in the cypress.env.json these are set like this.

```
{
  "DB_USERNAME": "THE-USERNAME",
  "DB_PASSWORD": "THE-PASSWORD",
  "DB_CONNECTION_STRING": "something.com/blabla.com"
}
```

The test just runs a cy.task() that executes code inside the db.js file.

How can I reference those env vars in the `.getConnection()` function?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how you are calling that function, you would need to pass in the config object instead of using `Cypress.env` use `config.env`.

**cypress.config.js - startup**

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import { oracledb } from ...

async function getConnection(config) {
  return oracledb.getConnection({
    user: config.env("DB_USERNAME"),
    password: config.env("DB_PASSWORD"),
    connectString: config.env("DB_CONNECTION_STRING")
  });
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      getConnection(config)
    },
  },
})
```

**cypress.config.js - task**

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import { oracledb } from ...

async function getConnection(config) {
  return oracledb.getConnection({
    user: config.env("DB_USERNAME"),
    password: config.env("DB_PASSWORD"),
    connectString: config.env("DB_CONNECTION_STRING")
  });
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        getConnection(config)
      }
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: That requires me to store the credentials in the cypress.config.js file. How can I do it so it takes the enviroment variables set in a specific enviroment?

Comment: No it doesn't  -  it's accessing them exactly the same as when you use `Cypress.env("DB_USERNAME")` because `config.env` is equivalent to `Cypress.env` - except the former is for the Node process and the latter is for the Browser process.

Comment: `console.log('env', config.env)` you will see everything from `cypress.env.json` is printed in the terminal.